# localhost error #500 MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress

Yesterday I transferred a live WordPress site and successfully setup my local dev environment using MAMP. I was able to get my database exported from my live site and imported locally. I was able to login and see my site, but to my surprise this morning, I am not able to access the site anymore. I am however able to access my localhost, but once I select and enter the root folder I get the always unwelcome "localhost is currently unable to handle this request. error 500".

I am not sure what's happened since yesterday to cause this and I've searched the forums, but I'm at a loss. I am new to local PHP development, so I might be missing something simple. I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: A 500 error in PHP should be logged in the Apache error log, where you'll find more details. Always when developing and testing code, you should enable PHP's error display by setting `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in your php.ini so all PHP's errors are immediately visible.  The 500 error could be a PHP issue, or it could be a problem with Apache's configuration. The log will tell you.

Comment: Change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your /wp-config file, it might offer some clues

Comment: Check the .htaccess file............................... is it there? does it have the right configuration?

Comment: Awesome tip. I activated the error_log. It appears to be a DB issue with one of the plugins. Should I import the live site's SQL DB again?

`Fatal error: Uncaught Daq_Db_Exception: Table 'dentalstaffingorg.zqvx_wpjb_job' doesn't exist occured in query:  do_action('init') ..... in /Users/Documents/Code/WordPress/dentalstaffingorg/wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/framework/Db/Query.php on line 423`

Comment: Also, I dug around in the console and could not find a .htaccess

Comment: When I remove the plugin wpjobboard I am allowed to see and enter the site, but the problem is, that plugin is the main part of my work, so I am not sure how to proceed. Thanks again for taking the time to help.